# How to Populate FullCalendar from a Database using Ajax and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, fullcalendar, asp.net-ajax

I am learning to use the FullCalendar.io and read through the documentation on the [FullCalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io/docs) site but have not been able to figure out how to update my database with the events created / changed from using the Calendar.

I am very new to this so any clear direction on saving events to the database would be appreciated.

So far I got a demo working but don't have any C# code yet as not sure how to get events data saved to database or pulled from database and displayed.

Here is what my calendar looks like:

[image]

**Here is the ASPX file:**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullcalendar.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/adminlte.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="/img/favicon.png">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand bg-white navbar-light border-bottom">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
            <a href="index.aspx" class="nav-link">Home</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </nav>

        <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
        <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-light-primary elevation-4">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div class="sidebar">
        <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
        <nav class="mt-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
        </aside>

        <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Testing Calendar</h1>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="./index.aspx">Home</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Reports</li>
            </ol>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-header -->

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" >
            <!-- SEARCH WEEKEND FEATURE -->             
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card">      
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="card">
                              <div class="card-header">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Draggable Events</h4>
                              </div>
                              <div class="card-body">
                                <!-- the events -->
                                <div id="external-events">
                                  <div class="external-event bg-success">Interview</div>
                                  <div class="external-event bg-warning">Payment</div>
                                  <div class="external-event bg-info">Tour</div>
                                  <div class="external-event bg-primary">Arrival</div>
                                  <div class="external-event bg-danger">Resign</div>
                                  <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label for="drop-remove">
                                      <input type="checkbox" id="drop-remove">
                                      remove after drop
                                    </label>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <!-- /.card-body -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /. box -->
                            <div class="card">
                              <div class="card-header">
                                <h3 class="card-title">Create Event</h3>
                              </div>
                              <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="btn-group" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                  <!--<button type="button" id="color-chooser-btn" class="btn btn-info btn-block dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Color <span class="caret"></span></button>-->
                                  <ul class="fc-color-picker" id="color-chooser">
                                    <li><a class="text-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="text-warning" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="text-success" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="text-danger" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="text-muted" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                                  </ul>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /btn-group -->
                                <div class="input-group">
                                  <input id="new-event" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Event Title">

                                  <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <button id="add-new-event" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat">Add</button>
                                  </div>
                                  <!-- /btn-group -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- /input-group -->
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>                        
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="card card-primary">
                              <div class="card-body p-0">
                                <!-- THE CALENDAR -->
                                <div id="calendar"></div>
                              </div>
                              <!-- /.card-body -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /. box -->
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>          

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json", | data: "{}",
             url: "calendar.aspx/GetEvents",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {
                $('div[id*=fullcal]').fullCalendar({
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    editable: true,
                    events: $.map(data.d, function (item, i) {
                        var event = new Object();
                        event.id = item.EventID;
                        event.start = new Date(item.StartDate);
                        event.end = new Date(item.EndDate);
                        event.title = item.EventName;
                        event.url = item.Url;
                        event.ImageType = item.ImageType;
                        return event;
                    }), 
                    eventRender: function (event, eventElement) {
                        if (event.ImageType) {
                            if (eventElement.find('span.fc-event-time').length){
                                eventElement.find('span.fc-event-time').before($(GetImage(event.ImageType)));
                            } else {
                                eventElement.find('span.fc-event-title').before($(GetImage(event.ImageType)));
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    loading: function (bool) {
                        if (bool) 
                            $('#loading').show();
                        else 
                            $('#loading').hide();
                    }
                });
             },
             error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
             {debugger;}
             });
         $('#loading').hide();$('div[id*=fullcal]').show();
    });
    function GetImage(type) 
    {
        if (type == 0) {
            return "<br/><i class='fa fa-money nav-icon text-info'></i><br/>"
        }
        else if (type == 1) {
            return "<br/><i class='fa fa-pie-chart nav-icon text-info'></i><br/>"
        }
        else
            return "<br/><i class='fa fa-calendar nav-icon text-info'></i><br/>"
    }
</script>
</div>                
</section>

<!-- REQUIRED SCRIPTS -->
</form>
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->
</div>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript">//</script>
<script src="js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="js/adminlte.js"></script>
<script src="js/demo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<!-- Page specific script -->
<script>
var events=new Array();
var numberofevents = this.serviceVariableGetDates.getTotal();
    for (i=0;i<numberofevents;i++)
    {
    //alert("numbrr:" + i);
    var dates=this.serviceVariableGetDates.getItem(i);
    console.log(dates.getData());
    var start_date = dates.getValue("c0");
    var end_date = dates.getValue("c1");
    var event_name = dates.getValue("c2");
    //var EventEntry = [ 'title: '+ event_name, 'start: '+ start_date,'end: '+ end_date ];
    event = new Object();       
    event.title = event_name; // this should be string
    event.start = start_date; // this should be date object
    event.end = end_date; // this should be date object
    event.color = "blue";
    event.allDay = false;
    this.label1.setCaption(start_date);
    //EventArray.push(EventEntry);
    console.log(events['title']);
    events.push(event);
    }
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource',events);
</script>   

<script>
  $(function () {

    /* initialize the external events
     -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function ini_events(ele) {
      ele.each(function () {

        // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
        // it doesn't need to have a start or end
        var eventObject = {
          title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
        }

        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject)

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
          zIndex        : 1070,
          revert        : true, // will cause the event to go back to its
          revertDuration: 0    //  original position after the drag
        })

      })
    }

    ini_events($('#external-events div.external-event'))

    /* initialize the calendar
     -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    //Date for the calendar events (dummy data)
    var date = new Date()
    var d    = date.getDate(),
        m    = date.getMonth(),
        y    = date.getFullYear()
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header    : {
        left  : 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right : 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      buttonText: {
        today: 'today',
        month: 'month',
        week : 'week',
        day  : 'day'
      },
      //Random default events
      events    : [ ],
      editable  : true,
      droppable : true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
      drop      : function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

        // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
        var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject')

        // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
        var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject)

        // assign it the date that was reported
        copiedEventObject.start           = date
        copiedEventObject.allDay          = allDay
        copiedEventObject.backgroundColor = $(this).css('background-color')
        copiedEventObject.borderColor     = $(this).css('border-color')

        // render the event on the calendar
        // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true)

        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
        if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
          // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
          $(this).remove()
        }

      }
    })

    /* ADDING EVENTS */
    var currColor = '#3c8dbc' //Red by default
    //Color chooser button
    var colorChooser = $('#color-chooser-btn')
    $('#color-chooser > li > a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      //Save color
      currColor = $(this).css('color')
      //Add color effect to button
      $('#add-new-event').css({
        'background-color': currColor,
        'border-color'    : currColor
      })
    })
    $('#add-new-event').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      //Get value and make sure it is not null
      var val = $('#new-event').val()
      if (val.length == 0) {
        return
      }

      //Create events
      var event = $('<div />')
      event.css({
        'background-color': currColor,
        'border-color'    : currColor,
        'color'           : '#fff'
      }).addClass('external-event')
      event.html(val)
      $('#external-events').prepend(event)

      //Add draggable funtionality
      ini_events(event)

      //Remove event from text input
      $('#new-event').val('')
    })
  })
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use a handler to get, or save data - look this page : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function   and where `myxmlfeed.php` use a handler, eg :`myxmlfeed.ashx`

Comment: Can you provide answer with sample code? I saw this but not sure how to use it in C# to connect to database.

Comment: I do not have use this one, so I do not have some code to give you. Now the way to connect to the database and get and return data is up to you... there are many ways.

Comment: That is what this question is about, what is one way to get the data?